# Checkout all projects to a certain branch

Tags: git, github, intellij-idea, version-control, intellij-14

I have 30 microservices opened in Intellij IDEA.
Is there any way I can **checkout all projects to master branch by 1 operation** ?

Comment: No, if all your microservices are in seperate git repos, you cannot use a git command for multiple repos. What you can do is write a Shell or Bash script which does goes into each repo and execute the git command "git checkout master"

Comment: If the tag `intellij-14` means you are still using [IntelliJ 14](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2014/11/intellij-idea-14-is-released/) then it's probably time to upgrade :)

Answer (score 1):

Go into **Settings > Version Control > Git** and check the checkbox for `Execute branch operations on all roots`. According to the alt-text of this checkbox:

> If selected, you would be able to checkout, compare, delete and create new branches in all Git roots with a single action. It will also affect behaviour of the push dialog.

Which seems to be what you're looking for. Note that this will only work when you have your microservices open in the same IntelliJ instance.

**Side note.** To view which roots IntelliJ is watching for VCS, click the **Version Control** tab in the settings tree. This will show all registered and unregistered roots.